# Lubuntu 19.04 Video After Image Problem

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, 19.04, gpu-driver

I'm using Lubuntu 19.04 on my Mac in a Virtualbox VM. I'm noticing only in my taskbar an after image of what used to be the most recently loaded dialog. This problem only appears in the taskbar. In this case, you can see the faint image of "Battery Info" in the taskbar.

[image]

Is that a feature of Lubuntu 19.04, is that a video driver issue, or is it some other issue?

Comment: I doubt very much that it's a feature. And I'm guessing video issues wouldn't be limited to the taskbar. I don't see any after-image on my VM running Lubuntu 19.04. How much RAM have you allocated to the VM?

Comment: It says 128MB video RAM and says I'm in the green with that. I have 3D Acceleration and Unscaled HiDPI both enabled, although I don't know if I need either of those. Base memory is half my system RAM, so 4GB. And 2 processors of my 4 CPUs, 100% execution cap.